# ffmpeg how to encode first then use it for another output

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to capture screen with gdigrab and combine int with a sound and then send it on my decklink sdi device.

here is my code to capture :

```
ffmpeg -framerate 25 -thread_queue_size 512 -f gdigrab -i title="Play" -f dshow -i audio="CABLE Output (VB-Audio Virtual Cable)" -af aresample=resampler=soxr -ar 48000 -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 2 -c:v libx264 -qp 0 -preset ultrafast "output.avi"
```

here is my code for output to ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i output.avi -f decklink -pix_fmt uyvy422 "DeckLink SDI (2)"
```

this way it works, but when I combine these two arguments to send the output to decklink card on the fly, ffmpeg stops working. here is the combination code :

```
ffmpeg -framerate 25 -thread_queue_size 512 -f gdigrab -i title="Play" -f dshow -i audio="CABLE Output (VB-Audio Virtual Cable)" -af aresample=resampler=soxr -ar 48000 -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 2  -f decklink -pix_fmt uyvy422 "DeckLink SDI (2)"
```

I have tried so many different combinations but no luck. it works only if i store it on a file then use that file as input. Is there a way to tell ffmpeg to use the result of first command as input of second command?

Thanks

**Update: 
Here is log report:**

```
    ffmpeg started on 2017-08-08 at 12:26:36
Report written to "ffmpeg-20170808-122636.log"
Command line:
ffmpeg -framerate 25 -thread_queue_size 512 -f gdigrab -i "title=Play" -c:v rawvideo -f dshow -i "audio=CABLE Output (VB-Audio Virtual Cable)" -af "aresample=resampler=soxr" -ar 48000 -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 2 -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 -f decklink -pix_fmt uyvy422 "DeckLink SDI (2)" -report
ffmpeg version N-71608-ga924b83 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      54. 23.101 / 54. 23.101
  libavcodec     56. 35.101 / 56. 35.101
  libavformat    56. 30.100 / 56. 30.100
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 14.100 /  5. 14.100
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Splitting the commandline.
Reading option '-framerate' ... matched as AVOption 'framerate' with argument '25'.
Reading option '-thread_queue_size' ... matched as option 'thread_queue_size' (set the maximum number of queued packets from the demuxer) with argument '512'.
Reading option '-f' ... matched as option 'f' (force format) with argument 'gdigrab'.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input file with argument 'title=Play'.
Reading option '-c:v' ... matched as option 'c' (codec name) with argument 'rawvideo'.
Reading option '-f' ... matched as option 'f' (force format) with argument 'dshow'.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input file with argument 'audio=CABLE Output (VB-Audio Virtual Cable)'.
Reading option '-af' ... matched as option 'af' (set audio filters) with argument 'aresample=resampler=soxr'.
Reading option '-ar' ... matched as option 'ar' (set audio sampling rate (in Hz)) with argument '48000'.
Reading option '-acodec' ... matched as option 'acodec' (force audio codec ('copy' to copy stream)) with argument 'pcm_s16le'.
Reading option '-ac' ... matched as option 'ac' (set number of audio channels) with argument '2'.
Reading option '-map' ... matched as option 'map' (set input stream mapping) with argument '0:v:0'.
Reading option '-map' ... matched as option 'map' (set input stream mapping) with argument '1:a:0'.
Reading option '-f' ... matched as option 'f' (force format) with argument 'decklink'.
Reading option '-pix_fmt' ... matched as option 'pix_fmt' (set pixel format) with argument 'uyvy422'.
Reading option 'DeckLink SDI (2)' ... matched as output file.
Reading option '-report' ... matched as option 'report' (generate a report) with argument '1'.
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Applying option report (generate a report) with argument 1.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input file title=Play.
Applying option thread_queue_size (set the maximum number of queued packets from the demuxer) with argument 512.
Applying option f (force format) with argument gdigrab.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: title=Play.
[gdigrab @ 0000000002d3f2a0] Found window Play, capturing 720x576x32 at (0,0)
[gdigrab @ 0000000002d3f2a0] Cursor pos (588,602) -> (-271,597)
[gdigrab @ 0000000002d3f2a0] All info found
Input #0, gdigrab, from 'title=Play':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1502178996.958615, bitrate: 331786 kb/s
    Stream #0:0, 1, 1/1000000: Video: bmp, bgra, 720x576, 331786 kb/s, 25 tbr, 1000k tbn, 25 tbc
Successfully opened the file.
Parsing a group of options: input file audio=CABLE Output (VB-Audio Virtual Cable).
Applying option c:v (codec name) with argument rawvideo.
Applying option f (force format) with argument dshow.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: audio=CABLE Output (VB-Audio Virtual Cable).
[dshow @ 0000000002d3c340] Selecting pin Capture on audio only
dshow passing through packet of type audio size  88200 timestamp 111632750000 orig timestamp 111632750000
[dshow @ 0000000002d3c340] All info found
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #1.0 : stereo
Input #1, dshow, from 'audio=CABLE Output (VB-Audio Virtual Cable)':
  Duration: N/A, start: 11163.275000, bitrate: 1411 kb/s
    Stream #1:0, 1, 1/10000000: Audio: pcm_s16le, 44100 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 1411 kb/s
Successfully opened the file.
Parsing a group of options: output file DeckLink SDI (2).
Applying option af (set audio filters) with argument aresample=resampler=soxr.
Applying option ar (set audio sampling rate (in Hz)) with argument 48000.
Applying option acodec (force audio codec ('copy' to copy stream)) with argument pcm_s16le.
Applying option ac (set number of audio channels) with argument 2.
Applying option map (set input stream mapping) with argument 0:v:0.
Applying option map (set input stream mapping) with argument 1:a:0.
Applying option f (force format) with argument decklink.
Applying option pix_fmt (set pixel format) with argument uyvy422.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an output file: DeckLink SDI (2).
Successfully opened the file.
detected 2 logical cores
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0000000002dd7ea0] Setting 'video_size' to value '720x576'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0000000002dd7ea0] Setting 'pix_fmt' to value '30'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0000000002dd7ea0] Setting 'time_base' to value '1/1000000'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0000000002dd7ea0] Setting 'pixel_aspect' to value '0/1'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0000000002dd7ea0] Setting 'sws_param' to value 'flags=2'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0000000002dd7ea0] Setting 'frame_rate' to value '25/1'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0000000002dd7ea0] w:720 h:576 pixfmt:bgra tb:1/1000000 fr:25/1 sar:0/1 sws_param:flags=2
[format @ 0000000002d3df00] compat: called with args=[uyvy422]
[format @ 0000000002d3df00] Setting 'pix_fmts' to value 'uyvy422'
[auto-inserted scaler 0 @ 0000000002d44ca0] Setting 'flags' to value '0x4'
[auto-inserted scaler 0 @ 0000000002d44ca0] w:iw h:ih flags:'0x4' interl:0
[format @ 0000000002d3df00] auto-inserting filter 'auto-inserted scaler 0' between the filter 'Parsed_null_0' and the filter 'format'
[AVFilterGraph @ 0000000002e586c0] query_formats: 4 queried, 2 merged, 1 already done, 0 delayed
[auto-inserted scaler 0 @ 0000000002d44ca0] w:720 h:576 fmt:bgra sar:0/1 -> w:720 h:576 fmt:uyvy422 sar:0/1 flags:0x4
[Parsed_aresample_0 @ 0000000002d513a0] Setting 'resampler' to value 'soxr'
[graph 1 input from stream 1:0 @ 0000000002d51460] Setting 'time_base' to value '1/44100'
[graph 1 input from stream 1:0 @ 0000000002d51460] Setting 'sample_rate' to value '44100'
[graph 1 input from stream 1:0 @ 0000000002d51460] Setting 'sample_fmt' to value 's16'
[graph 1 input from stream 1:0 @ 0000000002d51460] Setting 'channel_layout' to value '0x3'
[graph 1 input from stream 1:0 @ 0000000002d51460] tb:1/44100 samplefmt:s16 samplerate:44100 chlayout:0x3
[audio format for output stream 0:1 @ 0000000002d51520] Setting 'sample_fmts' to value 's16'
[audio format for output stream 0:1 @ 0000000002d51520] Setting 'sample_rates' to value '48000'
[audio format for output stream 0:1 @ 0000000002d51520] Setting 'channel_layouts' to value '0x3'
[AVFilterGraph @ 0000000002d4d0c0] query_formats: 4 queried, 9 merged, 0 already done, 0 delayed
[Parsed_aresample_0 @ 0000000002d513a0] ch:2 chl:stereo fmt:s16 r:44100Hz -> ch:2 chl:stereo fmt:s16 r:48000Hz
dshow passing through packet of type audio size  88200 timestamp 111637810000 orig timestamp 111637810000
[decklink @ 0000000002dd6a00] Found Decklink mode 720 x 576 with rate 25.00(i)
Output #0, decklink, to 'DeckLink SDI (2)':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.30.100
    Stream #0:0, 0, 1/25: Video: rawvideo (UYVY / 0x59565955), uyvy422, 720x576, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.35.101 rawvideo
    Stream #0:1, 0, 1/48000: Audio: pcm_s16le, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.35.101 pcm_s16le
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (bmp (native) -> rawvideo (native))
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (pcm_s16le (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[gdigrab @ 0000000002d3f2a0] Cursor pos (689,472) -> (-170,467)
[gdigrab @ 0000000002d3f2a0] Cursor pos (689,472) -> (-170,467)
[gdigrab @ 0000000002d3f2a0] Cursor pos (689,472) -> (-170,467)
[gdigrab @ 0000000002d3f2a0] Cursor pos (689,472) -> (-170,467)
Cliping frame in rate conversion by 0.000008
[gdigrab @ 0000000002d3f2a0] Cursor pos (689,472) -> (-170,467)
[decklink @ 0000000002dd6a00] Encoder did not produce proper pts, making some up.
[gdigrab @ 0000000002d3f2a0] Cursor pos (689,472) -> (-170,467)
*** 40 dup!
[gdigrab @ 0000000002d3f2a0] Cursor pos (689,472) -> (-170,467)
[gdigrab @ 0000000002d3f2a0] Cursor pos (689,472) -> (-170,467)
[decklink @ 0000000002dd6a00] Buffered video frames: 1.
[gdigrab @ 0000000002d3f2a0] Cursor pos (689,472) -> (-170,467)
[decklink @ 0000000002dd6a00] Buffered video frames: 2.
[gdigrab @ 0000000002d3f2a0] Cursor pos (689,472) -> (-170,467)
[decklink @ 0000000002dd6a00] Buffered video frames: 3.
[decklink @ 0000000002dd6a00] Buffered video frames: 4.
[decklink @ 0000000002dd6a00] Buffered video frames: 5.
[gdigrab @ 0000000002d3f2a0] Cursor pos (689,472) -> (-170,467)
[decklink @ 0000000002dd6a00] Buffered video frames: 6.
[decklink @ 0000000002dd6a00] Buffered video frames: 7.
[gdigrab @ 0000000002d3f2a0] Cursor pos (689,472) -> (-170,467)
[decklink @ 0000000002dd6a00] Buffered video frames: 8.
[decklink @ 0000000002dd6a00] Buffered video frames: 9.
[decklink @ 0000000002dd6a00] Buffered video frames: 10.
[gdigrab @ 0000000002d3f2a0] Cursor pos (689,472) -> (-170,467)
[decklink @ 0000000002dd6a00] Buffered video frames: 11.
[decklink @ 0000000002dd6a00] Buffered video frames: 12.
[gdigrab @ 0000000002d3f2a0] Cursor pos (689,472) -> (-170,467)
[decklink @ 0000000002dd6a00] Buffered video frames: 13.
[gdigrab @ 0000000002d3f2a0] Cursor pos (689,472) -> (-170,467)
[gdigrab @ 0000000002d3f2a0] Cursor pos (689,472) -> (-170,467)
dshow passing through packet of type audio size  88200 timestamp 111642810000 orig timestamp 111642810000
[gdigrab @ 0000000002d3f2a0] Cursor pos (689,472) -> (-170,467)
[gdigrab @ 0000000002d3f2a0] Cursor pos (689,472) -> (-170,467)
[gdigrab @ 0000000002d3f2a0] Cursor pos (689,472) -> (-170,467)
[gdigrab @ 0000000002d3f2a0] Cursor pos (689,472) -> (-170,467)
[gdigrab @ 0000000002d3f2a0] Cursor pos (689,472) -> (-170,467)
[decklink @ 0000000002dd6a00] Buffered video frames: 14.
[decklink @ 0000000002dd6a00] Ending audio preroll.
[decklink @ 0000000002dd6a00] Starting scheduled playback.
[decklink @ 0000000002dd6a00] Buffered video frames: 15.
[decklink @ 0000000002dd6a00] Buffered video frames: 16.
[decklink @ 0000000002dd6a00] Buffered video frames: 17.
[decklink @ 0000000002dd6a00] Buffered video frames: 18.
[decklink @ 0000000002dd6a00] Buffered video frames: 19.
[decklink @ 0000000002dd6a00] Buffered video frames: 20.
[decklink @ 0000000002dd6a00] Buffered video frames: 21.
[decklink @ 0000000002dd6a00] Buffered video frames: 22.
[decklink @ 0000000002dd6a00] Buffered video frames: 23.
[decklink @ 0000000002dd6a00] Buffered video frames: 24.
[gdigrab @ 0000000002d3f2a0] Cursor pos (689,472) -> (-170,467)
[gdigrab @ 0000000002d3f2a0] Cursor pos (689,472) -> (-170,467)
[gdigrab @ 0000000002d3f2a0] Cursor pos (689,472) -> (-170,467)
[gdigrab @ 0000000002d3f2a0] Cursor pos (689,472) -> (-170,467)
[decklink @ 0000000002dd6a00] Buffered video frames: 24.
[gdigrab @ 0000000002d3f2a0] Cursor pos (689,472) -> (-170,467)
[gdigrab @ 0000000002d3f2a0] Cursor pos (689,472) -> (-170,467)
[gdigrab @ 0000000002d3f2a0] Cursor pos (689,472) -> (-170,467)
[gdigrab @ 0000000002d3f2a0] Cursor pos (689,472) -> (-170,467)
[gdigrab @ 0000000002d3f2a0] Cursor pos (689,472) -> (-170,467)
[gdigrab @ 0000000002d3f2a0] Cursor pos (689,472) -> (-170,467)
[gdigrab @ 0000000002d3f2a0] Cursor pos (689,472) -> (-170,467)
frame=   42 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:01.68 bitrate=N/A dup=40 drop=0    
[gdigrab @ 0000000002d3f2a0] Cursor pos (689,472) -> (-170,467)
dshow passing through packet of type audio size  88200 timestamp 111647710000 orig timestamp 111647710000
[gdigrab @ 0000000002d3f2a0] Cursor pos (689,472) -> (-170,467)
[gdigrab @ 0000000002d3f2a0] Cursor pos (689,472) -> (-170,467)
[gdigrab @ 0000000002d3f2a0] Cursor pos (689,472) -> (-170,467)
[gdigrab @ 0000000002d3f2a0] Cursor pos (814,496) -> (-45,491)
[gdigrab @ 0000000002d3f2a0] Cursor pos (814,496) -> (-45,491)
[gdigrab @ 0000000002d3f2a0] Cursor pos (811,497) -> (-48,492)
[gdigrab @ 0000000002d3f2a0] Cursor pos (811,497) -> (-48,492)
[gdigrab @ 0000000002d3f2a0] Cursor pos (811,497) -> (-48,492)
[gdigrab @ 0000000002d3f2a0] Cursor pos (806,497) -> (-53,492)
```

Comment: in this way I have to make a delay before use the file. That's the price

Comment: "ffmpeg stops working" – why? Getting any error? Please show the command line output from your last command.

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe the ffmpeg output to another ffmpeg. However, you need to know video resolution because you need to tell second ffmpeg the correct resolution. I resize the input to 1080p in the following sample, you can change to what you want. However, please make sure the resolution and framerate is supported by your DeckLink card.

```
ffmpeg -framerate 25 -thread_queue_size 512 -f gdigrab -i title="Play" -f rawvideo -s 1920x1080 -pix_fmt uyvy422 - | ffmpeg -f rawvideo -video_size 1920x1080 -framerate 25 -pixel_format uyvy422 -i - -f dshow -i audio="CABLE Output (VB-Audio Virtual Cable)" -af aresample=resampler=soxr -ar 48000 -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 2 -f decklink "DeckLink SDI (2)"
```

Comment: Thanks a million. It's working, although I changed some parameters as you mentioned.

Comment: Specifying the size, pixel format and framerate is not necessary – you can also mux the raw video into NUT or MKV, then pipe that.

Comment: Thanks @slhck , could you make an example?

Comment: Good suggestion @slhck. Here is the refined command:
ffmpeg -framerate 25 -thread_queue_size 512 -f gdigrab -i title="Play" -c:v rawvideo -f matroska - | ffmpeg -f matroska -i - -f dshow -i audio="CABLE Output (VB-Audio Virtual Cable)" -af aresample=resampler=soxr -ar 48000 -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 2 -f decklink "DeckLink SDI (2)"

Comment: By running new command I'm getting this error:
Raw RGB is not supported Natively in Matroska, you can use AVI or NUT or
If you would like to store it anyway using VFW mode, enable allow_raw_vfw (-allow_raw_vfw 1)

Comment: another problem that I'm facing is that the sound is 1 sec ahead from video. Is it possible to combine video and audio first then pipe it to ffmpeg for decklink output?

Comment: You may thy this:
ffmpeg -framerate 25 -thread_queue_size 512 -f gdigrab -i title="Play" -f dshow -i audio="CABLE Output (VB-Audio Virtual Cable)" -af aresample=resampler=soxr -ar 48000 -c:a pcm_s16le -ac 2 -c:v rawvideo -f NUT - | ffmpeg -f NUT -i - -c copy -f decklink "DeckLink SDI (2)"